# Complexe sql query from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with my query: 
So, I have a table call supplier:

```
ref_article    supplier_id
1903           10
```

I have another table call gift:

```
id_gift        etat          id_adresse       ref_article
100455         3               1              1903
100456         3               2              1903
100457         3               3              1903
```

And I have the table gift_adresse:

```
id             name           surname
1               jkkjl         hkj
2               hjhjk         jklj
3               kjkj          hjjkhk
```

My query is like this:

```
SELECT
supp.ref_article,
COUNT(g.id_instant_gagnant) AS gifts_number
FROM supplier supp
LEFT JOIN gift g ON supp.ref_article = g.ref_article
INNER JOIN gift_adresse g_adr ON g.id_adresse = g_adr.id_adresse
WHERE supp.supplier_id = 10 AND g_ig.etat = 3
GROUP BY g.ref_article
```

For this query I get:

```
ref_article    gifts_number
1903           3
```

The problem is that I want to get all `id_gift` for this ref_article for my example : 100455,100456,100457
Is it possible to do in a single query?

Comment: mysql <> sql server. which one are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT(expr)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for the desired CSV output.

**MySQL Solution**:

```
SELECT
       supp.ref_article
     , COUNT(g.id_instant_gagnant) AS gifts_number
     , GROUP_CONCAT(g.id_gift) AS gift_ids
  FROM supplier supp
  LEFT JOIN gift g ON supp.ref_article = g.ref_article
       INNER JOIN gift_adresse g_adr ON g.id_adresse = g_adr.id_adresse
 WHERE supp.supplier_id = 10 
   AND g_ig.etat = 3
 GROUP BY g.ref_article
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your direct question is `group_concat()`.  However, your query is rather awkward:

```
SELECT supp.ref_article,
      COUNT(g.id_instant_gagnant) AS gifts_number
FROM supplier supp LEFT JOIN
-------------------^ LEFT JOIN is turned to inner join
     gift g
     ON supp.ref_article = g.ref_article INNER JOIN
     gift_adresse g_adr
     ON g.id_adresse = g_adr.id_adresse
--------^ by this expression here
WHERE supp.supplier_id = 10 AND g_ig.etat = 3
--------------------------------^ I don't know what this is
GROUP BY g.ref_article
---------^ Don't aggregate by a `LEFT JOIN`ed table unless you want `NULL` values *AND* this is not the expression in the `FROM`
```

I would suggest dispensing with the `LEFT JOIN`, fixing the references in the table, and removing the third table:

```
SELECT supp.ref_article,
       COUNT(g.id_instant_gagnant) AS gifts_number,
       GROUP_CONCAT(g.id_gift) as gifts
FROM supplier supp JOIN
     gift g
     ON supp.ref_article = g.ref_article and g.etat = 3
WHERE supp.supplier_id = 10 
GROUP BY supp.ref_article
```

If you want a `LEFT JOIN`, you can now add it back in.  The condition on `etat` is in the `ON` clause, where it would need to be.